# start, stop stanzas in upstart

Tags: upstart

I recently started working with Upstart and I ran across these two lines so was trying to understand what does this mean?

```
start on stopped rc
stop on runlevel [!2345]
```

What does `start on stopped rc` line do? And what does `stop on runlevel [!2345]` do?

Answer (score 1):

From the Upstart Cookbook, [Standard idioms](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#standard-idioms):

> If you want the job to start "around the time" (actually just after)
>   the equivalent System-V job would run, specify:
>
> ```
> start on stopped rc
> ```

And from [Determining the stop on Condition](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#determining-the-stop-on-condition-ubuntu-specific):

> Shut down is not as event rich as startup. A common idiom is to
>   specify your stop on as:
>
> ```
> stop on runlevel [016]
> ```
>
> This ensures the job will be stopped on shutdown, when switching to
>   single-user mode and on reboot.

`runlevel [016]` == `runlevel [!2345]`.

Comment: Can you help me understand what does this line **`If you want the job to start "around the time" (actually just after) the equivalent System-V job would run`** mean?

Comment: If you written an `/etc/init.d` script instead of an Upstart job, then that script would have been started around this time. What that time is exactly depends on the job, it's dependencies, etc.

Comment: The reason why I asked this is because of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965895/upstart-script-is-not-getting-started-during-reboot-sometimes). Somehow my script is not getting started up whenever we reboot the box. It work sometimes but sometimes it doesnt work at all. And after I added this runlevel `start on stopped rc` instead of my other `start` runlevel, it works everytime and I am confuse how come changing to this, it works fine. Do you know what could be the reason?